# Как добавить все элементы из массива, который находится в файле .bin в другой массив(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет!
Подскажите, есть ли возможность добавить все элементы массива(который находится в файле с расширением `.bin`) в другой массив и вывести через print. Я использую метод `.fromfile()`, первым аргументом он запрашивает путь, а второй обязательный — количество элементов, которые мы хотим добавить. А что если я не знаю сколько там элементов и хочу добавить все, то как мне быть? Название файла, из которого беру массив я ввожу в терминале благодаря `sys`

Код, который я использую с методом `fromfile()`

```
import sys
from array import array

file_array = sys.argv[1]
my_array = array('i')

with open(file_array, 'rb') as input_array:
    my_array.fromfile(input_array, 4)
    print(my_array)
```

Comment: а язык программирования какой?

Comment: упс, python, извиняюсь)

Comment: размер файла разделить на размер элемента?

Comment: @MBo что-то сложно, да и тем более я не знаю размер элемента. Мне кажется должен быть какой-то метод, который добавит все элементы в массиве

Comment: При использовании массива вы размер знаете, определив 'i'. Можно и попробовать использовать очень большое число, обработав исключение, при этом сколько есть - добавится. А вам точно в Python нужен массив? Это не совсем традиционно...

Comment: @MBo а если предположить, что тебе просто скинули файл с расширением .bin, в котором есть массив, но ты соответственно прочитать его не можешь. Получается только через обработчик ошибок ? А по поводу традиционности, то мне неизвестно, я только обучаюсь, вот и стало интересно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
my_array.fromfile(input_array, -1)
```

my_array.fromfile(input_array, -1) считывает все данные из файла в массив my_array, в то время как код my_array.fromfile(input_array, 4) считывает только 4 целых числа из файла в массив my_array. Итак, основное отличие заключается в том, что первый считывает все данные из файла, в то время как второй считывает только 4 целых числа из файла.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!) это то что я и искал)